# Sort criteria - sorted()

Tags: python, sorting

I'd like to sort a list following two criteria in this order:

1. Numerical order; then
2. Alphabetical order.

I'm currently using:

```
from re import search
my_list = ['nelsonfreire87956423', 'martha34685128', 'gleen34685128', 'polini13452678']

first_sort = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: [x])

sorted_list = sorted(
    first_sort, 
    key=lambda x: search(r'\d{8}', x).group() if search(r'\d{8}', x) else []
)
print(sorted_list)
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
['polini13452678', 'gleen34685128', 'martha34685128', 'nelsonfreire87956423']
```

I'd like to know how I can sort this list with just *one* `sorted` call. I mean, how can I pass multiple criteria to `sorted`?

Comment: You know the first sort is just `sorted(my_list)`, right? Putting each item into another list doesn't make any difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `key` function can return *a tuple*, where the elements at each position in the tuple are used to break ties from the elements at the previous position. For example:

```
def my_key(s):
    name, num = search(r'(\D+)(\d+)', s).groups()
    return int(num), name
```

which results in:

```
>>> my_key('nelsonfreire87956423')
(87956423, 'nelsonfreire')  # i.e. sort on number first, then name
```

and therefore:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=my_key)
['polini13452678', 'gleen34685128', 'martha34685128', 'nelsonfreire87956423']
```